# Databricks CLI "config host mismatch" Error in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, command-line-interface, aws-databricks, databricks-cli

I'm encountering an issue when trying to import notebooks from GitLab into a Databricks workspace shared folder using Jenkins. When I execute the command:

```scss
databricks workspace import-dir --profile DEFAULT ./notebooks Shared/test --overwrite
```

I receive the following error:

```scss
panic: config host mismatch: profile uses host https://dbc-bf3e73e7-221d.cloud.databricks.com, but CLI configured to use <databricks-host>
```

To configure the Databricks CLI, I used the command:

```scss
databricks configure --token '$databricksToken' --host '$workspaceUrl'
```

Upon verification, the host URL that I configured matches the URL displayed in the error message. Does anyone have a solution to this mismatch issue?

Comment: add the version of Databricks CLI and other relevant information